# My App was not working in nexus mobile with error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java, android, cross-platform, smartface.io

We developed a app where it was working all mobiles, but not working in nexus,
and we are getting below error:

```
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "RAND_egd" referenced by "/data/app/com.teletextholidays.app-1/lib/arm/libsprat-jni.so"...
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at io.smartface.plugin.SMFPlugin.loadLibrary(SMFPlugin.java:20)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at com.geniem.sprat.SpratAndroidActivity.<clinit>(SpratAndroidActivity.java:435)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 10-27 17:14:07.121: E/AndroidRuntime(4315):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 10-27 17:14:07.779: E/RenderingContextPopulator(1675): Incomplete configuration for trafficCardSharing.shareLocation
 10-27 17:14:07.779: E/RenderingContextPopulator(1675): Incomplete configuration for trafficCardSharing.shareCommute
 10-27 17:14:07.779: E/RenderingContextPopulator(1675): Incomplete configuration for trafficCardSharing.userPromptedToShareCommute
```

Comment: Note: We Developed the our App with Smartface Frame Work

Comment: We Observed That ,this error was getting only in nexus

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because smartface is not supported in the latest version of android, 6.0 i.e. Marshmallow.